Expo Router not routing to the screen when clicked on push notification
I have implemented push notification in my expo managed app using latest expo router file based routing. However i see that when i send notification from expo push notification tool the routing works when i send url:/path in data however when i do the same thing from firebase fcm it does not route me to the path. please help!
below is the code for the reference:
const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();

  // Firebase Analytics Start

  const pathname = usePathname();
  const params = useGlobalSearchParams();

  // Track the location in your analytics provider here.

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if analytics is available
    if (analytics) {
      // Log a custom event with the screen name and params
      analytics().logEvent("screen_view", {
        screen_name: pathname,
        screen_params: params.toString(),
      });

      // Log screen view
      analytics().logScreenView({
        screen_name: pathname,
        screen_class: pathname, // You can adjust this if needed
      });
      console.log(pathname);
    }
  }, [pathname, params]);

  // Firebase Analytics End

  // Tracking Transparency Start
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestTrackingPermission = async () => {
      try {
        // Delaying the initial permission request by 500 milliseconds
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

        const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();

        if (status === "granted") {
          console.log("Yay! I have user permission to track data");
        } else {
          console.log("User denied permission for tracking");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error requesting tracking permission:", error);
      }
    };

    requestTrackingPermission();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    console.log(inAppMessaging().isMessagesDisplaySuppressed);
    inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const token = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
      if (isMounted) {
        setExpoPushToken(token);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
        console.log("Received notification:", notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        redirect(response.notification);
        console.log('Notification response received:', response);
      });

    Notifications.getLastNotificationResponseAsync().then((response) => {
      if (isMounted && response?.notification) {
        redirect(response.notification);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  // Get the notification token of FCM
  // async function getDeviceNativePushToken() {
  //   const { data: token } = await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync();
  //   console.log("Device native push token: ", token);
  //   return token;
  // }

  // getDeviceNativePushToken();
  function redirect(notification) {
    // Safely access the URL using optional chaining
    const url = notification?.request?.content?.data?.url;
  
    // Check if the URL is truthy before navigating
    if (url) {
      console.log("Redirecting to:", url);
      router.push(url);
    } else {
      console.log("No URL found in the notification data");
    }
  }
  // Push Notifications End

